# Dynamic custom new domain mapping in K8s ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Has anyone tried or aware of mapping dynamic runtime custom domain mapping to Ngnix ingress/load balancer in K8s?

We are already aware of one solution to manually map custom domain by adding new host and tls in ingress file, that is working fine.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  - host: example1.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  .
  .
  .
  .
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: example-site-secret-name
  - hosts:
    - example1.com
    secretName: example1-site-secret-name
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

But it has limitations that require app restart and manual changes in ingress. So looking for any other better alternative way which would work at scale.

Scenario and query similar to what is asked here,
https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/b7ty6p/nginx_ingress_and_dynamic_ssl_certificates/

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43633